# Magento attribute url not found error 404 /l/ page filter

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting

everyone 
I have a problem about attribute url filter page can not found. It show error 404 and there are /l/ on url. 
according to this this page. http://www.siameyewear.com/brands.html
At the backend. I have enable Is Anchor to yes. and check Use All Available Attributes. To show attribute Product Listing Sort By bra bra bra.

At this page. http://www.siameyewear.com/brands.html
On your left hand side. You will see Product Listing Sort By. Which is create by magento attribute. 
But my problem is. When I'm click on a link. What ever link under a word "Shop By" It's will show error 404 page can't be found.

For example. When i'm click on a Rayban Link under a word "Shop By" It's will show a error 404 and url will look like this http://www.siameyewear.com/brands/l/rayban.html
I don't know where the /l/ came from. I have try to remove /l/ by myself. It's still not show a correct page.

Anyone know how to fix this problem. Kindly please help. 
Thank you so much

Answer (score -3):

Problem solved. Just remove some stupid seo enterpr...

Comment: This is not at all an answer